# Const being ignored in template function parameter list

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, visual-c++

I'm having a problem with function definitions in template classes.

I have a template class `Array` that has a member function `IndexOf`:

```
// Defined in header
template <typename T>
class Array {
    // Other stuff

    int IndexOf(const T value) const {
        // Code of function
    };

    // Other stuff
};
```

When I create an instance of the array with a class pointer, The function *ignores* the `const T` and just uses `T`. So when I call the function with a `const T`, there is a compiler error: "No instance of overloaded function":

```
#include "Array.h"

class Object{
    // Object stuff
};

int main(){
    // Demonstration code
    Array<Object*> objects = Array<Object*>(); // Array of Object*
    Object* obj = new Object();                // An Object*
    const Object* cobj = new Object();         // A const Object*

    // This works fine
    objects.IndexOf(obj); // No problems

    // This has compile error
    objects.IndexOf(cobj); // No idea why

    delete obj;
    delete cobj;

    return 0;
}
```

The code seems to *forget* that the function's parameter is `const T`. The function parameter should be `const Object*`, but it treats the parameter like its just `Object*`.

Any idea why this happens?

The error does not occur if I am not using a pointer as the type.

The code inside the function would not cause problems.

Before it is said, no, I will not use `std::vector` or others of the like to have a dynamically resizing array. That takes all the fun out of it.

Comment: `const T value` where `T` is `Object*` is `Object* const value`. The `const` in `const T value` applies to `value` and does not modify `T`.

Comment: Got some *real* code ? Clearly this isn't an MCVE. Regardless, the `const` in your template is being applied to the pointer-of, not the pointed-to. `cobj` is a regular pointer to a const `Object`. The template expects a const pointer to a regular `Object`. The seeming irregularity you're not quite seeing is one of several reasons why I always apply `const` in suffix form rather than use the compilers "handy" prefix form. Consistency, right?.

Comment: One could solve this with some Template-Meta-Programming stuff using [std::remove_reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference) and a struct specialization for detection of pointers (a case switch) such that the most inner type would be made const.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In reality your declaration of the function can be seen as:

```
 IndexOf(const (Object *) val)
```

which basically means that the `Object *` should point to the const object as here:

```
 Object *const cobj = new Object();
```

Now you will have correct behavior.
However if you are really interested in const pointers, then you need to modify your declaration as:

```
  Array<const Object *> objects;
```

Answer (score 0):

`const T value` where `T` is `Object*` is `Object* const value`. The `const` in `const T value` applies to `value` and does not modify `T`. `const T value` is a `value` of type `T` that can't change, which for pointers means can't be assigned a new address. It's clear that the following function could not be called with a `const Object *`.

```
int IndexOf(Object * const value) const // const pointer to non-const Object
```

To add `const`ness to the pointed-to type, you can use type-traits to get the pointed-to type, add const to it and then produce a new pointer type from it. For example :

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
using add_const_to_ptr =
    std::add_pointer_t<
    std::add_const_t<
    std::remove_pointer_t<T>>>;
```

The usage of which would look like :

```
template<class T>
struct container {
    void push(add_const_to_ptr<T> ptr) {
        (void)ptr;
    }
};

struct bar {};

int main()
{
    const bar cbar;
    bar mbar;

    container<bar*> my_container;

    my_container.push(&mbar);
    my_container.push(&cbar);
}
```

Though this assumes `container` will only be used with pointers, in which case it may be better to make `T` refer to the type of object pointed to, rather than a pointer type. If `T` may or may not be a pointer type, the type trait can be improved by checking if `T` is actually a pointer with `std::conditional` :

```
#include <type_traits>
template<class T>
using add_const_to_ptr =
std::conditional_t<std::is_pointer<T>::value,
    std::add_pointer_t<
    std::add_const_t<
    std::remove_pointer_t<T>>>,
    T>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare `Array<Object*>::IndexOf()` as template:

```
template <typename U>
int IndexOf(const U& value) const {
    // Code of function
}
```

and inside you'll compare `value` to the contents of the array and that comparison will cast the contents from `Object*` to `const Object*` which is of course allowed.

Also with this approach you can pass to that function anything that `T` can be converted from/to.